# Zeptojs on() not triggering

Tags: zepto

I have build a plugin `(pluginA)` based on `zeptojs` and inside this plugin I fetch data using ajax and attach a list of `<a href=""></a>`

How do I bind an event to these anchors? I was going for something globally like `<a href="..." data-key="ABC123"></a>` and then use `$('[data-key]').pluginB()` and then inside `pluginB()` have something like

`$(this).on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });` but I am not able to bind the click event to anchors created dynamically.

I tried adding `$('a').on('click', ...)` before I call `pluginA()` but it's not firing.

What I really would like would be to use the `bind()` `trigger()` approach in order to decouple the two plugins, but I am having trouble finding a good example.

Comment: I may have found the problem. My $('a').on('click', ...) is being attached before the ajax request is done inside pluginA.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegating form of `on` to bind all desired links in a particular area (in this example, the entire body):

```
$(body).on('click', 'a[data-key]', function(e) {e.preventDefault();...});
```

Now all links with `data-key` will trigger your function, regardless of whether or not they were present at the time you called `on`; subsequently-added links will automatically get the behavior, and removed links won't leak memory by holding dangling handler references.